# simple search with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

hy 
 i try to create a simple search on my application

**calendar.rb**

```
def self.search(search_condition)
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
  find( :all, :conditions => ['city like ?', search_condition])
end
```

**calendar_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @search = @user.calendar.search(params[:search_condition])
  @content_calendars = @user.calendar.all
  @content_calendars_by_dates = @content_calendars.group_by(&:published_on)
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
end
```

the partial **_search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag root_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search_condition], :id => 'search_field' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>   
<% end %
```

when i try i get this error:

`The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL /.`
 i dont understand why ?

**rake routes**

```
user_calendars GET    /users/:user_id/calendars(.:format)   calendars#index

POST   /users/:user_id/calendars(.:format)          calendars#create

new_user_calendar GET    /users/:user_id/calendars/new(.:format)      calendars#new

edit_user_calendar GET    /users/:user_id/calendars/:id/edit(.:format) calendars#edit

user_calendar GET    /users/:user_id/calendars/:id(.:format)      calendars#show
```

Comment: What is your root path set as?

Comment: i try to get all of my search in my index .                       root to => "home#index"                                           rake routes                                                       root / home#index

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag needs to route to the calendar index action.  Like this:

```
<%= form_tag(user_calendars_path(@user), :method => 'get')  do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search_condition], :id => 'search_field' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %> 

<% end %>
```

EDIT: Figured it out, here's the real problem:

Your route for calendars#create is the same as your route for calendars#index.

```
/users/:user_id/calendars(.:format)
```

You need to change your routes.rb file to differentiate between them.  Traditionally the plural path goes to the index action.

Comment: what do you means by I missed that you needed a @user.id for your routes initially

Comment: your calendar index path requires a user id.  user_calendars GET    /users/:user_id/calendars(.:format)   calendars#index

Comment: but if i try that <%= form_tag user_calendars_path(:id), i get this error The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL /. ???

Comment: I see the problem now. Edited my answer